# How can I run an existing Django application?

Tags: django

What is the command-line command for running an existing Django app?

I created the project and the app, but I forgot what the command to start the app was.

Comment: Did you refer the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: yes but then it marks all the import in my files with error!

Answer (score 0):

You don't start the app. You run the entire project(or host).
The command to run the project is

```
 python manage.py runserver
```

after this go to the url you provided in urls.py file.